# Data Lake Analytics - Large vertex query

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a simple query which make a GROUP BY using two fields:

```
@facturas =
    SELECT a.CodFactura,
       Convert.ToInt32(a.Fecha.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) AS DateKey,           
      SUM(a.Consumo) AS Consumo
    FROM @table_facturas AS a
    GROUP BY a.CodFactura, a.DateKey;
```

@table_facturas has 4100 rows but query takes several minutes to finish. Seeing the graph explorer I see it uses 2500 vertices because I'm having 2500 CodFactura+DateKey unique rows. I don't know if it normal ADAL behaviour. Is there any way to reduce the vertices number and execute this query faster?

Answer (score 0):

First: I am not sure your query actually will compile. You would need the Convert expression in your `GROUP BY` or do it in a previous `SELECT` statement.

Secondly: In order to answer your question, we would need to know how the full query is defined. Where does `@table_facturas` come from? How was it produced?

Without this information, I can only give some wild speculative guesses:

1. If @table_facturas is coming from an actual U-SQL Table, your table is over partitioned/fragmented. This could be because:

   - you inserted a lot of data originally with a distribution on the grouping columns and you either have a predicate that reduces the number of rows per partition and/or you do not have uptodate statistics (run `CREATE STATISTICS` on the columns).
   - you did a lot of `INSERT` statements, each inserting a small number of rows into the table, thus creating a big number of individual files. This will "scale-out" the processing as well. Use `ALTER TABLE REBUILD` to recompact.
2. If it is coming from a fileset, you may have too many small files in the input. See if you can merge them into less, larger files.

You can also try to hint a small number of rows in your query that creates @table_facturas if the above does not help by adding `OPTION(ROWCOUNT=4000)`.